# Android 10 ACTION_GET_CONTENT image with GPS info?

Tags: android, gps, exif, android-10.0

I'm using ACTION_GET_CONTENT to let user import photos into my app. It reads GPS data from selected photos. It worked fine up until Android 10.

I found that I'm supposed to use `MediaStore.setRequireOriginal()` on the uri but `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor()` throws an error

```
SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider
...obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

The original uri doesn't contain GPS exif data.

I added the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission with no luck. Photos are imported but GPS exif is lost. `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage` in Manifest doesn't seem to change this.

How am supposed to use this ? ACTION_GET_CONTENT examples don't use gps data from exif and MediaStore examples don't use ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

My code:

```
    public void openGallery(View v) {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        photoPickerIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 4);
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            ...
            Uri selecteduri = data.getData();
            ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(selecteduri, "r");
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
            copyPhoto(fileDescriptor, localFile);
            ...
    }
```

---

another failed attempt:

```
                        Uri selecteduri = data.getData();
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selecteduri, null, null, null, null);
                        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                            String[] parts = cursor.getString(0).split(":");
                            Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, parts[1]);
                            photoUri = MediaStore.setRequireOriginal(photoUri);
                            InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(photoUri);
                            ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(stream);
                            double[] returnedLatLong = exifInterface.getLatLong();
                            stream.close();
                        }
```

getLatLong still returns null

---

Update:

Using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` returns the same Uri. MediaStore.setRequireOriginal() just adds `?requireOriginal=1` to it and openFileDescriptor throws Permission Denial, unless I open it as `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + id` with setRequireOriginal() which still strips GPS info.

Comment: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` definitely provided access to EXIF headers [through Q Beta 4](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131889251). I am surprised that `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is giving you different results, but you might try `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead. The only place I was seeing EXIF data redactions was from `MediaStore`.

Comment: @CommonsWare updated, but I'm still getting the same result

Comment: Did you solve the issue?